# Excel can't establish with xlwings connection when running from standalone Python app from Excel

Tags: excel, python-2.7, xlwings

I am trying to create standalone app from a script with xlwings. I used both py2exe and cx_freeze. Both work just fine outside Excel (I added some tests). When I import either of them as a VBA macros in Excel, they also work fine. But so far, on my computer only. I asked my friend to check if the script works on her computer and she got the following error:

[image]

So I thought it make sense to figure out whether I do something wrong. I sent her a Fibonacci example and it raised sort of the same error:

[image]

It should be something wrong with names of the files, but it's not like obvious for me what exactly. Maybe somebody already knows how to deal with it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If files are downloaded from the internet, they only work right away in the first instance of Excel. Meaning: Your friend should try to close Excel completely. Also check in the Task Manager if there is still an `EXCEL` process running and if so, kill it. Then try again in a fresh instance of Excel.

**update:**
Ah I see - the problem seems to be a bug happening when there are unicode characters involved in the file path! I've opened a issue [here](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/154). In the meantime, try to run the file on a path without unicode characters.

Comment: Indeed, it works with non-unicode path. Why did I not notice it myself! However, she says there are still some troubles with my package packed with cx-Freeze (with py2exe works fine) -- it gets Windows 123 error. And thanks for the useful comment about running Excel as a first instance. Maybe, I'll try to test it on more machines.